# Mongorestore max file size

Tags: mongodb, file, size, max, mongorestore

After `mongodump` my database is 3.08 Gb. I have a lot of bson-files bigger than 100 Mb and even 1 file more than 1 Gb. After `mongorestore` I'm receiving following error:

```
SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket excep                                                                                                  tion [RECV_ERROR] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
DBClientCursor::init call() failed assertion: 10276 DBClientBase::findN: 
transport error: 127.0.0.1:27017 ns: bfshina.$cmd query:  
{ getlasterror: 1 }
```

I suppose that my files are too big. Is there any way to increase file size limit?